# Moving Oracle SQL CLOB values(>4000 chars) to SQL Server without trimming

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I'm building ETL in SSIS, and have to move data from Oracle DB to data warehouse on MS SQL Server.

I am facing a problem with migrating contents of columns of datatype CLOB.
So far I was casting CLOB values to VARCHAR using:

```
dbms_lob.substr(*columnName*, 4000, 1)
```

I could then easily write such contents as nvarchar in SQL Sevrer.

However I would not like to force-trim everything- how can I move entire content of CLOB (when exceeds 4000chars) in a format that's going be recognized by SSIS/SQL Server?

Can I cast CLOB as any other datatype without trimming it?

Comment: can you use nvarchar(max) or varbinary?

Comment: @Jeremy the problem is on Oracle side; SSIS won't process incomming CLOB values- question is what can I convert CLOB into at Oracle side, before it's even reached SSIS/MSSQL.

Comment: Would it be possible to chunk your CLOBs into varchar2(4000) pieces and then string them back together on the MS SQL Server side?